# package manager not working because of dash

Tags: apt, dpkg

I guess my package manager is not working because `dash` is not available.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install hello
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  hello
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
184 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/119 kB of archives.
After this operation, 111 kB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package dash (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dash
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ hello
Command 'hello' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install hello              # version 2.10, or
sudo apt  install hello              # version 2.10-2ubuntu4
sudo apt  install hello-traditional  # version 2.10-5
See 'snap info hello' for additional versions.
```

Comment: Packages are built for specific releases, you've not told us yours, thus we're limited to given *generic* advice.  Have you told your system to attempt fixes?  eg. `sudo apt -f install` & like commands.  The `dash` package relates to a prior problem you've ignored & needed to be fixed first.

Comment: It's telling you that the packaging system is so unhappy with the state of the `dash` package (and 184 others) that it cannot continue. You must repair the packaging system problems before you can use it. Start with `sudo apt update;sudo apt upgrade`. Read the results carefully. Very carefully! Your sysrem teeters on the edge. Backup your system.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. It's pretty easy. It worked when I typed the following line.

```
sudo apt reinstall dash
```